# Which English is spoken in continental Europe? British, American , or its own version

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Many Europeans speak English. What version is this English? is it British, American or its own continental English? If it's continental English which does it most closely resemble, British or American, in pronunciation and spelling?

Edit: I mean continental Europe. From the comments below, it is clear the native language accents will be there in the English they speak. If we speak of people who regularly speak with other European Nationals what type of English do they speak? For example Ursula Von Der Leyen?

Comment: All the three, depending on what country they live in and to which English they are most exposed to by the media, travels etc.

Comment: It's very hard to generalise, but maybe you want to refine your question. Most people watch a lot of US media, but also travel to the UK and Ireland. Schools I believe often teach UK English but will use US media too; but I can't find a reference right now. Universities and businesses are another question. Also see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162347/is-the-english-language-used-by-the-european-institutions-the-british-one) about the version of English used by European institutions.

Comment: English is learned in school as a second language in most EU countries. One should survey the curricula of various schools in those countries, and see what variety of English they are teaching. I imagine the target is mainly British English (with some mention of Americanisms as appropriate), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Quick check -- how do they spell colo(u)r?

Comment: One of the largest differences between British English and American English is the pronunciation. There are Americans teachers of English, British teachers of English in European schools, and European teachers of English in European schools. 

Presumably, the Americans teach American pronunciation, the Brits teach British pronunciations, and the Europeans teach whatever variety they learned. It's quite hard for most native English speakers to switch to different accents.

Comment: Beyond accents, and even in writing, there's a distinct flavour to some nationalities' English, which diminishes but doesn't completely disappear with fluency. Native speakers of German, for example, often give themselves away with word orders that wouldn't be the first choice of a native English speaker (even if they might be acceptable). In some contexts words are used that are correct but not common in everyday speech - but the direct translation in the speaker's native language is widely used

Comment: Can you specify if by continental Europe you mean mainland Europe or the entire continent together with the islands (such as Malta and Sicily)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no scientific data, but as a British scientist who has worked in France, Germany, The Netherlands and Italy — and has heard Continental European politicians using English, I would say that the **accent/pronunciation** is usually British†.

Part of the reason for this is, I would suggest, that it is customary for university language students to spend a year (generally teaching) in a country where their language of specialization is spoken. Britain is obviously a closer and cheaper venue than the US, and there are exchange schemes between European countries. When these students become schoolteachers, they teach with the accent they have acquired. They probably also use British terminology and spelling, although school textbooks may negate the latter.

(Similar reasons explain the use of Castilian Spanish — rather than S. American Spanish — in Britain and Continental Europe.)

---

† Obviously most non-native speakers have an accent influenced by their native language, but one can still tell the difference between British and American styles of pronunciation.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that to me. In  your opinion, in the EU office a person from one nationality will be able to tell what nationality(European) the other person belongs to just by hearing his/her spoken English.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Swedish study on this "[British or American English? - Attitudes, Awareness and Usage among Pupils in a Secondary School](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:241524/fulltext01.pdf)" Ann-Kristin Alftberg June 2009

> Another finding is that the variety selected also seems to be dependent on specific vocabulary items, some of which are “school” related and therefore influenced by British English, whereas others are “non-school” related, mainly exposed through media, and mostly influenced by American English (Mobärg 2002:127).
>
> The mixture of British English and American English in pupils‟ speech tends to increase. A study made by Margareta W. Axelsson about students‟ usage and attitudes in 2000, shows that 69% of the students mixed features from these two varieties when they were reading a text aloud.

I have no reason to believe that this pattern is not repeated across Europe: They are formally taught British English but pick up American English.

Comment: So continental Europeans will know which nationality the speaker belongs when that other person speaks English?

Comment: I don't think that would follow as a result - from personal experience second language speakers tend to mix both forms freely but good second-language speakers of English can detect American and English accents.

Answer (score 1):

I have had Italian students whose accents were unequivocally American either because they lived most of their formative years in the USA, or had the fortune to visit the country several times in their young lives. On top of that, American TV series, movies on Netflix, pop songs etc. are US dominated so that greatly influences lexical choice and pronunciation.

But in my experience, Italian state teachers who teach English to middle and high-school students overwhelmingly continue to teach British English. Whether this is also true in Scandinavian countries like Sweden or Denmark, Germany or in other countries in southern Europe such as Greece, Spain, Turkey or Albania I can't say but after Brexit—the UK is no longer part of the [Schengen Area](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-countries-list/) and no longer participates in the [Erasmus programme](https://erasmus-plus.ec.europa.eu/the-uk-and-erasmus)— the future trend will probably be American English.

Comment: The UK has never been a part of the Schengen Area.

Comment: @jsw29 No? Yet my family and I could always travel to the UK without a passport, just our ID cards were sufficient. The last time we went to the UK was in November 2019, when we travelled by car. Only Swiss customs stopped us to check our luggage and identification.